# Easier way to find a CloudPage by ID on Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, lookup, cloudpage

Within MarketingCloud cloud Pages, you can use redirect links using the page ID as wrote in the line below

`RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(457))`

How can I easily find CloudPage with id `457` through the Cloudpages UI ?

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange user1100023, it may help to provide some more information and details so that others can fully understand your question and what you've been trying to do or where you are seeing this.

Comment: I did @SamuelDeRycke.

Answer (score 0):

When you viewing all the pages, there are three lines next to delete button (bin) click on these three lines and you will see the id.

Kind Regards

Comment: Thanks @Dell. I was wondering if I could search for a page using the ID. I have more that 60 pages and it is quite painful to lookup

Answer (score 0):

I found one option with latest release of Marketing Cloud, New CloudPages Experience Preview

Run report - CloudPages Impressions by Page Report,you will get the list of page with Name and ID,

To find the page by ID, go to web studio, New CloudPages Experience Preview, landing page views, search the Name of the page associated with the id based on the report generated in above step.